# Angular (v5+) - Snackbar "openFromComponent", component communication

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, snackbar

Angular (v5.2.10) [Snackbar](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api)

**--| Intro |--**
I have one Angular component (let's call it "Parent") initializing an Angular material Snackbar called `snackBar`. Passed in is `SnackbarMessage` , another component with a template containing the snackbar markup. Using `snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackBarMessage)` is necessary in this instance because I need to use more than just plain text in the snackbar [like markup, click events, etc] where `snackBar.open(message, action)` is not enough.

**--| Code |--**
*"Parent" component:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class Parent implements AfterViewInit {

  public constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarMessage);
  }

  public dismissSnackbar(): void {
    this.snackBar.dismiss();
  }
}
```

*"SnackbarMessage" component:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-snackbar-message',
  templateUrl: './snackbar-message.html'
})
export class SnackbarMessage { }
```

*"snackbar-message.html" markup:*

```
<p>(Snackbar message)</p>
<button type="button" (click)="dismissSnackbar();">Dismiss</button>
```

**--| Issue |--**
Within the imported `SnackbarMessage` template (snackbar-message.html) I need to call the Parent component's `dismissSnackbar();`, how do we do this with the current encapsulation of this Angular app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yatharth's solution will work.

However, if you want to future-proof your components, you should use a service. With a service, you can dismiss your snackbar from anywhere in the app -- not just the snackbar message component like in his approach.

Create an observable stream, and subscribe to it in your snackbar component. It will just pass a boolean (true or false), and you can toggle your snackbar component with that value every time a new value is emitted in the stream.

Simple example:

```
@Injectable()
export class SnackbarService {
    status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    status$: Observable<boolean> = this.status.asObservable();
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-snackbar-message',
    templateUrl: './snackbar-message.html'
})
export class SnackbarMessage { 
    open: boolean = false;

    constructor(public snackbarService: SnackbarService) {
        snackbarService.status$.subscribe((open: boolean) => this.open = open);
    }
}
```

Now from anywhere in your app, all you have to do is this to open the snackbar:

```
snackbarService.status.next(true);
```

Or this to close the snackbar:

```
snackbarService.status.next(false);
```

---

And if you want to get more cases than just open/closed, you can use an enum with different values:

```
export enum SnackbarStatus {
    Open,
    Closed,
    SomethingElse
}
```

Pass an enum in your observable stream, instead of a boolean:

```
@Injectable()
export class SnackbarService {
    status: BehaviorSubject<SnackbarStatus> = new BehaviorSubject(SnackbarStatus.Closed);
    status$: Observable<SnackbarStatus> = this.status.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Great explanation, this solution will work good with how I need this to be implemented. Thank you good sir

Answer (score 15):

You don't actually need to call the parent component's "dismissSnackbar()" method to dismiss the snackbar. You can simply inject the "MatSnackBar" into the "SnackbarMessage" component and call "dismiss()" method on that injected instance of "MatSnackBar". As written in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api), this will hide the currently visible Snackbar i.e. the Snackbar opened using "SnackbarMessage" component in your example. Below is your updated "SnackbarMessage" component:-

**"SnackbarMessage" component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-snackbar-message',
    templateUrl: './snackbar-message.html'
})
export class SnackbarMessage { 
    constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

    public dismissSnackbar(): void {
        this.snackBar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not overly complicated +1

Comment: If you need to use methods from MatSnackBarRef, e.g. dismissWithAction(), you can inject it too. `private matSnackBar: MatSnackBarRef<MatSnackBar>`.

Answer (score 10):

I solved today a problem similar to yours using `MatSnackBar.openFromTemplate` instead of `MatSnackBar.openFromComponent`. With this approach, all features from the child component becomes directly accessible from the parent component.

The 'Parent Component' acts as a 'Mediator' class between `MatSnackBar` and the `SnackBarMessageComponent`. Now, the `SnackBarMessageComponent` is decoupled of a MatSnackBar and becomes a plain component and could be renamed to `MessageComponent`. You can send and receive data between parent and child component using plain `@Input` and `@Output`. You can add as many `@Input`s or `@Output`s as you want.

The code says more than 1.000 words:

#### parent.component.html

```
<h1>parent component</h1>
<ng-template #snackBarTemplate>
    <app-message [msg]="message" (onDismissClick)="dismissSnackbar"></app-message>
</ng-template>
```

#### parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
export class Parent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('snackBarTemplate')
  snackBarTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  public message: string;

  public constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.message = '(Snackbar message)';
     this.snackBar.openFromTemplate(snackBarTemplate);
  }

  public dismissSnackbar(): void {
     this.snackBar.dismiss();
  }
}
```

#### message.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-message',
  templateUrl: './message.html'
})
export class MessageComponent { 
    @Input()
    msg: string;

    @Output()
    onDismissClick= new EventEmitter<any>();

    dismissClicked() {
       this.onDismissClick.emit(null);
    }

}
```

#### message.component.html

```
<p>{{msg}}</p>
<button type="button" (click)="dismissClicked()">Dismiss</button>
```

(The above code has not been tested)

Answer (score 0):

Use the ComponentRef to call your method.

**MyCustomSnackBarComponent** with your custom method

```
public miMethod(): void { 
    console.log('call from parent');
}
```

Component where you created an instance of **MyCustomSnackBarComponent**:

```
const snackBarRef = this.snackbar.openFromComponent(MyCustomSnackBarComponent);
snackBarRef.instance.miMethod();
```

this solution still applies if your method has parameters